# Can typescript define an interface structure based on key condition?

Tags: typescript

I want to define a `Person` type, as such:

```
interface Person  {
    gender: 'male'|'female';
    pants?: string;
    skirt?: string;
}
```

However, I want to make it more specific, whenever the `gender=male`, then `pants` must exist, or if `gender=female`, then `skirt` must exist, something like this:

```
interface Person {                Person {
    gender: 'male';     [OR]          gender: 'female';
    pants: string;                    skirt: string;
}                                  }
```

Both are similar object, except have few keys different. Is it possible? Is this a good practice in typing an object?

I hope I can do something like:

```
interface Person {
    gender: 'male'|'female'|'elf'|'undead';
    head?: string;
    pants?: string exists if gender='male';
    skirt?: string exists if gender='female';
    leg?: string;
    tail?: string exists if gender='elf'|'undead';
}
```

Haha... Probably I think too much...

Comment: Perhaps by extending the interface to have `interface MalePerson extends Person` or `interface FemalePerson extends Person`?

Comment: Is that the only way? Hmmm... because if I extend the interface, I probably have many `sub-interface`, then my `.ts` file will full with `import` interface statement... Hmmm...

Comment: you can have an index.ts file in the models folder and import all the required classes/interfaces there and import only the models folder in your component.

Comment: ok, then i will use `extends` and apply `index.ts` import... thanks everyone...

Comment: It seems that you want a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), where `gender` is the discriminant.  Is there something about that solution which wouldn't work for you?  (And if so, can you add detail to the question?)

Comment: thanks for the info. I have looked into it, and seems it is very advance. :)

Comment: Why don't you just make two objects and create one if one condition is met and another if a different condition is met?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the `interface` style method, you can use discriminated unions.

Below is the answer. Tested using TypeScript 3.1.3.

```
type Person = {
    gender: "male";
    pants: string;
} | {
    gender: "female";
    skirt: string;
};
```

In this case, (if I'm not mistaken), `gender` is known as the `discriminant`, it can help the compiler static analyzer to identified which type you wanted to use.

For example,

```
let x: Person = { 
    gender: "male",
    skirt: "red" // <-- Compile error, because when gender is "male", `skirt` does not exist
    // <-- Another error, property `pants` is missing
}
```

For more information, try studying [discriminated unions in TypeScript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/discriminated-unions.html).